# Tablesorter how to disable styling for nested tables?

Tags: css, tablesorter

I'm using tablesorter for styling a table, in the table I also have a nested table which I would like to style differently, but the tablesorter classes and styles override mine.

Is there a way to prevent nested tables from inheriting the table sorter styles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to modify the css to add [css child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) between every element as you travel down the DOM tree... this makes the definition very specific about which table elements are to be styled.

For example, if your outer table has an ID of "outer", then this css will only style the outer table:

```css
/* header cells */
#outer > thead > tr > th { background: blue; color: white; }
/* zebra striping */
#outer > tbody > tr { background: white; }
#outer > tbody > tr:nth-child(2n) { background: lightblue; }
```

The nested tables will not be styled by the above css (unless they are left unstyled). You will then need to follow this same pattern to style the nested tables with their own specific ID or class and child selectors between each element.

Comment: Thank you, the outer table is the one I want the default table sorter styling applied to, the inner table is the one I want to leave unstyled or styled differently.

Comment: Can you clarify how I would apply with the out table having the class table sorter and an inner table not ?

Comment: I have a [high-specificity blue theme](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/css/high-specificity/theme.blue.specific.css) which you can use as a template - I had to fix a few issues in it which are now available in v2.28.4; you can see it work in [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/k9uasLc7/).

Comment: Thank you I will download and take a look.

Comment: I've only just got around to try this out, unfortunately it appears that the other scripts I have associated with table sorter are no longer compatible...one of the errors I have $.tablesorter is now undefined.

Comment: anything to add on my previous comment?

Comment: One reason `$.tablesorter` would be undefined would be if you load jQuery more than once.

Comment: as far as I am aware I am only loading jQuery once, is there any way to determine this ?  I don't see any reported errors or warnings in Mozilla debugger.